# linux network interface irq smp_affinity

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, interrupt

I am doing network performance tests, and realized the interface's interrupts processing on 8 cpus is not balanced. So I want to make them more balanced.

I just set the files :

```
echo 11 > /proc/irq/16/smp_affinity
echo 22 > /proc/irq/17/smp_affinity
echo 44 > /proc/irq/18/smp_affinity
echo 88 > /proc/irq/19/smp_affinity
```

where the 16 17 18 and 19 are my four IRQ no of my network interfaces.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/interrupts | grep ens
  16:      30490          0      16838     427032        379          0      10678          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   vmwgfx, ens34, ens42
  17:     799858          0      68176          0      78056          0      44715          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ioc0, ens35, ens43, ens39
  18:       2673          0       6149          0       7651          0       5585          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb2, snd_ens1371, ens40, ens44
  19:     145769    1431206          0          0          0          0        305          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, ens41, ens45, ens33
```

But, sadly, I still found the IRQ is not balanced over the CPUs:

```
Tasks: 263 total,   2 running, 261 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  7.5 us, 10.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 65.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.4 hi, 16.7 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  9.7 us, 15.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 59.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi, 16.2 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  : 11.7 us, 21.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 66.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  : 10.4 us, 16.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 66.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  6.9 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  : 10.9 us, 24.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 64.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu5  : 11.8 us, 29.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 58.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  :  9.0 us, 19.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 71.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  : 11.5 us, 22.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 65.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

So, why the IRQs not occur on all CPUs?

How can I balance the irq processing over all CPUs?

Comment: Did you turn off `irqbalance` daemon? What is your system, it has single socket motherboard or it is NUMA; what is your network card (which chip it uses), how it is connected to the system and how you work with network?

Comment: what irqbalance for ? it is running. my system is CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406: 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64, vmware guest.

Comment: Chinaxing, http://linux.die.net/man/1/irqbalance - it is program to periodically rebalance interrupt affinity. Try to disable it before test, if you set manual irq affiinity. Also, you should start from *NOT VIRTUALIZED case*, not from vmware guest, but with host os. There can be problem in vmware network driver. What is your real network card, and how it is connected to the virtual machine? What is the Host os?

Comment: Host os is centos, I use bridge mode to connect to virtual machine. real network card will impact the vmware guest host's network card ? does it mocked by vmware (so no relative) ?

Comment: by the way. I change the /sys/class/net/$if/queue/rx-0/rx_cpus likely have some affect , so, what the effect of these location ?